# Java/Spring - Send Post Request to retrieve a PDF-File from anoter Rest Endpoint

Tags: java, spring

I would like to do a simple POST-Http-Request in Java, with an Object as Payload (Serialized as JSON - I have the Gson Library included). The Endpoint retrieves a PDF-File depending on the JSON-Payload of the request.

When I try it with Postman the PDF gets retrieved correctly.
*But how can I do this in java and even return the File from my function then?*

This is my code I have so far, the request seems to be working, but it seems like it doesn't have any payload:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/print")
public String printCompetences(@RequestBody final PrintCompetences competences)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String requestPayLoad = gson.toJson(competences);
    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create("http://localhost:5001"))
            .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(requestPayLoad))
            .build();

    HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request,
                            HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    System.out.println(response.body());
    return gson.toJson(response.body());
}
```

Comment: Should the `response.body()` contain the PDF binary or what? What are you actually returning from `printCompetences`?

Comment: localhost:5001 returns me a pdf binary which i can save when i use postman/curl. I want to reach that through this function, so yes printCompetences should return the PDF binary

Answer (score 0):

One option is to stream bytes to `HttpServletResponse`. If you change your method declaration into:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/print", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
public String printCompetences(@RequestBody final PrintCompetences competences, 
                                            HttpServletResponse servletResponse)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
```

you can stream pdf bytes directly into `servletResponse` like:

```
// Not String but InputStream. ByteArray might work also for binary but why not to stream
HttpResponse<InputStream> response = 
    client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
// I use here Apache commons IOUtils to write bytes
IOUtils.copy(response.body(), servletResponse.getOutputStream());
```